# Combining common function in controllers AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller, code-reuse

I am working with the project. I am using pagination, checkAll, deleteAll like functionalities that are common between all controllers. I wish to move the code to factory or service so can be utilize to all controllers. I tried but not clear with perfection. I want hint. 
I know to create factory or service, and how to intefrate it controller but bit confuse with logic of moving similar code.

I give example that I use to write in all controller, Logic for Sorting and pagination as well.

```
$scope.bigCurrentPage = 1;
$scope.editIndex = "";

var sortKey = "name";
var sortDirection = "ASC";
$scope.filterObj = {order: [sortKey + " " + sortDirection], limit: CONFIG.limit, offset: 0};
$scope.filterObj.offset = ($scope.bigCurrentPage - 1) * CONFIG.limit;

$scope.sortList = function (inputSort) {
    if (sortKey === inputSort) {
        sortDirection = (sortDirection === "ASC") ? "DESC" : "ASC";
    } else {
        sortKey = inputSort;
    }
    $scope.filterObj.order = [sortKey + " " + sortDirection];
    $scope.pageChanged();
}


$scope.getSongs = function () {
    $scope.filterObj.offset = ($scope.bigCurrentPage - 1) * CONFIG.limit;
    Song.find({filter: $scope.filterObj})
            .$promise
            .then(function (data) {
                $scope.items = data;
                $scope.maxSize = 5;
                $scope.size = $scope.filterObj.limit;
                $scope.countingIndex = ($scope.bigCurrentPage - 1) * $scope.filterObj.limit; //Its idea to implement counting. Variable is not part of pagination..////     
            });
};


$scope.pageChanged = function () {
    $scope.getSongs();
};

$scope.pageChanged();
```

This way, suppose I am doing this for Albums and I would change sortKey as 'id', Will use services with 'Album.find', would change 'filter' object and I am done, but fact is I am using common code in all controllers. How would I write it in better way.

Comment: Since you are using a bunch of $scope then services would not be appropriate.  Make yourself a base controller class and inherit from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do have lots of properties which are very hard to maintain in service, so I'd suggest that you should use controller rather than service,(Or put reusable variable in service that would make more code sense). Below is created controller can be inject-able in any other controller using `$controller` dependency.

**Common Controller**

```
app.controller('commonCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.bigCurrentPage = 1;
    $scope.editIndex = "";

    var sortKey = "name";
    var sortDirection = "ASC";
    $scope.filterObj = {
        order: [sortKey + " " + sortDirection],
        limit: CONFIG.limit,
        offset: 0
    };
    $scope.filterObj.offset = ($scope.bigCurrentPage - 1) * CONFIG.limit;

    $scope.sortList = function(inputSort) {
        if (sortKey === inputSort) {
            sortDirection = (sortDirection === "ASC") ? "DESC" : "ASC";
        } else {
            sortKey = inputSort;
        }
        $scope.filterObj.order = [sortKey + " " + sortDirection];
        $scope.pageChanged();
    }

    $scope.getSongs = function() {
        $scope.filterObj.offset = ($scope.bigCurrentPage - 1) * CONFIG.limit;
        Song.find({
                filter: $scope.filterObj
            })
            .$promise
            .then(function(data) {
                $scope.items = data;
                $scope.maxSize = 5;
                $scope.size = $scope.filterObj.limit;
                $scope.countingIndex = ($scope.bigCurrentPage - 1) * $scope.filterObj.limit; //Its idea to implement counting. Variable is not part of pagination..////     
            });
    };

    $scope.pageChanged = function() {
        $scope.getSongs();
    };

    $scope.pageChanged();
});
```

You could inject this created `commonCtrl` to any other controller using $controller dependency, `commonCtrl` shares it scope to the controller where it gets injected. But changes done from `controllerA` in `commonCtrl` would not be available in `controllerB` because `commonCtrl` gave copy of its scope to the controller who inject it.

**Controller A**

```
app.controller('controllerA', function($scope, $controller){
   $controller('commonCtrl', {$scope: $scope}); //inject commonCtrl scope to current scope
   //common scope will be available from here
})
```

**NOTE**

> If you want changes to be reflected in other controller you could use
>   service with this controller which would share common properties to
>   different controllers.

Comment: Can you please explain with bit example in ControllerA. It would be more easy. How would I pass dependency from controllerA to commonCtrl. As I am using the same with different service set. One more question would it work if I use to controllers on same page as ControllerA and ControllerB

Comment: Would it work separately for both Controllers A and B??

Comment: No it will only give `commonCtrl` copy to `controllerA` changes in `commonCtrl` from `controllerA` will not available in `controllerB`, I'll add more info the..Do you want the changes done from `controllerA` should available in `controllerB`

Comment: No, I think that would be achieve from factory that changes from ControllerA reflects in ControllerB. Am I right?

Comment: @Sankalp  Yes you are right, please do look at my updated answer